# Sharing Notebook with or as Public Link

Tags: note-taking

I want to share my entire notebook collection and I'm looking for a public shared link which can be accessed by anyone like website

Does any note taking app has the capability to share entire notebook collection with search as well?

Many allows to share a note, sharing collection but without search

Thanks